# How to pass custom EventArgs to UI controls

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

Unfortunately I was not able to find relevant answer to my problem. I have a object encoder that has an event "VideoEncoding". It passes custom EncodingEventArgs that include various Properties like Progress, Size etc. I can output this info to Console or write to text file. But when I try to utilize it in WinForms I'm not able to pass that information to UI like label or progress bar. I tried different approaches. Background Worker seems like a good idea, The problem is that Background Worker cannot subscribe to VideoEncoding event, neither it will take my custom EventArgs. This is what i was able to put together. Maybe there is a different way to do it using delegates that would communicate with UI. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    private BackgroundWorker bw;
    int _progress;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        this.bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);        
        this.bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        this.bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = "The job is: " + e.Result.ToString();
        this.button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "% complete";

    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;


        this.Encode

        worker.ReportProgress(_progress);


        e.Result = "Completed";
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!this.bw.IsBusy)
        {
            this.bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            this.button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }





    public void Encode()
    {

        var job = new EncodingJob();
        //setup encoding job

        //subscribe to an event
        ffmpeg.VideoEncoding += GetProgress;           

        ffmpeg.DoWork(job);

    }



    public void GetProgress(object sender, EncodingEventArgs e)
    {
        _progress = (int)e.Progress;


    }


  }
```

Comment: What's the question here? Does the code work?

Comment: It is possible to start encoding job, but it is not possible to see its progress. Encoding job is on different threat and its progress cannot be passed directly to UI. That's why we need background worker or other delegate to pass that info to UI somehow. To answer you question, encoding yes, seeing progress no.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the background workers `ReportProgress` in the `GetProgress` Method. How should the form know your progress if you don't signalize it?

Comment: Thank you. I realized after the fact that I need to raise the  ReportProgress event but not for worker object but for bw object in GetProgress method. Everything worked perfectly.